# SQL how to get a result from between a set of date without knowing the specific date?

Tags: mysql

I am sending a HTTP request to my PHP file using javascript, I get the date by using the normal getDate() function, however I dont know what that day is since each day it will be a different date.

What I need is a SQL query that checks the date, and return any values from that date plus any results from 2 days before and two days after, is there such a query for this?

For example:

```
SELECT col FROM somewhere WHERE MY_DATE = 'VARIABLE_WITH_DATE' BETWEEN 2 days before and 2 days after VARIABLE_WITH_DATE
```

Its important to keep in mind that I dont know what date it is, ofcourse if I knew the date I could do a SQL query much easier.

I can do some hack on javascript to fix this issue, but would be nice to know if there is such a SQL query.

Im using MySql

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many product are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @Jarlh im using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT col 
FROM somewhere 
WHERE DATE(MY_DATE) BETWEEN 
SUBDATE(IFNULL(VARIABLE_WITH_DATE,NOW()),INTERVAL 2 DAY)
AND ADDDATE(IFNULL(VARIABLE_WITH_DATE,NOW()),INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

[MySQL SUBDATE() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_subdate.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT col 
FROM somewhere 
WHERE MY_DATE BETWEEN dateadd(day,-2,VARIABLE_WITH_DATE) 
and dateadd(day,2,VARIABLE_WITH_DATE)
```

You can read more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp

Comment: Im not sure what dateadd and dd on your code means?

Comment: dateadd is a function that manipulates date variables in sql. It goes like this dateadd( type[day/month/year], value[1,2,3,...], variable to be manipulated).  dd means day so the function will do the following: it will take VARIABLE_WITH_DATE and First subtract 2 days from it and in the second it will add two days